# maven-war-plugin copies only subdirectories (including files). Not just files

Tags: java, maven, maven-war-plugin

I am using the maven-war-plugin (version 3.3.2) in order to copy a jar file from target/lib/v1 into the WEB-INF/lib of the WAR file.

The jar file is located under: **target/lib/v1/myJar.jar**

The pom.xml looks like this:

```
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <webResources>
            <resource>
              <directory>${project.build.directory}/lib/v1</directory>
              <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
            </resource>
          </webResources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work as the jar is not copied under WEB-INF/lib.

I have the feeling that the maven-war-plugin is looking for a folder to copy.

I modified my pom.xml as shown below (I removed the v1):

```
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <webResources>
            <resource>
              <directory>${project.build.directory}/lib</directory>
              <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
            </resource>
          </webResources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

and the jar was copied, but with the subfolder v1.

So, the WAR was like this:

```
    └── WEB-INF
          └─── lib
                └── v1
                     └── myJar.jar
```

But this one doesn't help, as the jar has to be directly under lib.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: The maven-war-plugin is not intended to copy things?.. Why do you need to do that? I

Comment: Because my WAR file is included in an EAR file and the maven-ear-plugin that I use, moves all jars into the root lib of the EAR file. But I need this particular myJar.jar under the WEB-INF/lib of the WAR file.

Comment: If it's moved you are using skinny wars which means it's duplicated in other wars as well. so where is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't copy only the jar file into the WAR file, but the whole directory v1/myJar.jar
But this changes the structure of the WAR and it doesn't work.

Comment: It sounds like a circle because it's removed because it's duplicated ...why do you have a directory v1 somewhere? The lib directory is not allowed to have a sub directory .... ??

Comment: The myJar.jar is not duplicated. I have let's say myJar1.jar under v1 and myJar2.jar under v2.
myJar1.jar should be added under WEB-INF/lib of WAR file 1
myJar2.jar should be added under WEB-INF/lib of WAR file 2
The reason for subfolders v1 and v2 is that I want to have 2 different versions of the module running in parallel.

Comment: That does not work...because the classloading will not really support that based on the standards... Only directory lib is supported as far as I know...

Answer (score 0):

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.3.2</version>
<configuration>
    <webResources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/lib/v1</directory>
            <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>myJar.jar</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </webResources>
</configuration>
```

With this configuration, only the myJar.jar file will be copied to WEB-INF/lib without the v1 subfolder. The resulting WAR file structure will be as follows:

```
└── WEB-INF
      └─── lib
            └── myJar.jar
```

you can specify the specific files you want to include, and any subdirectories will be ignored. This way, you can achieve the desired flattened directory structure in the WAR file.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work, as nothing is copied under the WEB-INF/lib of the WAR file.